# Isolated storage common for other apps in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I'm trying to create a WP8 application which authenticates against a portal and gets an authentication cookie.

I would like to be able to store this cookie in some "common storage" within the phone, so that other applications are able to access it as well. This way, once the application authenticates against the portal, other apps which need access to this cookie can simply go to the common storage and fetch it rather than the authentication application "passing" the cookie around.

In other words:

1. Authentication app contacts UAG, gets a cookie, stores is in some
   common accessible location - lets say the file is C:\tmp\foo.txt
   (using a noddy filepath I know)
2. When the user now launches some other app, the app first checks to    see if the file C:\tmp\foo.txt exists, and if it does, it consumes it    and carries forward

From what I have read, there is no easy way to do so. It seems there isn't a common storage area available for all apps. Is the above possible?

Thanks

PS: The place where photos are stored is accessible to other apps. Is that specific to that folder? IF so, can we put other content in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for now, this isn't possible. Each app on Windows Phone becomes its own 'Isolated Storage' which is not accessible for other apps.

Comment: I had a feeling that might be the case :(, I tried using KnownFolders to see if I could get access to some high privileged folders but that didn't work either. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

You could try storing the files in a skydrive folder. Windows Phone now has a Live SDK that allows you to push and pull files from a users cloud storage.

Check out this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826550.aspx

Comment: Yea I thought of that, but the data needs to be secured on the device, and also this would mean the other apps need an active internet connection to be able to get the data from Skydrive. Thanks for the suggestion though